# В билде программы написаной на C# находит вирус

Tags: c#, visual-studio, вирусы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Отправил свою программу мини-игру друзьям, написаную на c# - антивирус нашел в ней HEUR/QVM03.0.0000.Malware.Gen.
Хотя никаких вирусов конечно же я там не писал. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело.

Comment: Например, может быть ложное срабатывание. Попробуйте внести небольшие изменения в код и перекомпилироваться.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998715/visual-studio-2015-community-trojan-heur-qvm03-0-malware-gen вот здесь похожая проблема. Внизу есть ответ что можно попробовать сделать. Ну и нельзя исключать что к экзешнику в итоге действительно прицепился вирус.

Comment: Посмотрите "родственные" файлы на VirusTotal по похожим сигнатурам - есть вероятность, что Security 360 не ошибся.

Comment: Это False Positive -- ложное срабатывание. В таких случаях я посылаю файл по почте авторам антивируса и они обновляют базы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, **вируса у вас нет**. Это просто антивирус "эвристиками" откопал подозрительные паттерны. В число "подозрительных паттернов" входят использование упаковщиков, игры с секциями исполняемого файла и прочие совершенно безобидные вещи.

Я прекрасно помню, как мой файл, представляющий собой однострочный эквивалент RunDll32, но с манифестом в ресурсах, половина "антивирусов" считала подозрительным только потому, что я воспользовался редким упаковщиком FSG.

"Эвристики" бесполезны чуть менее, чем полностью. Они — чуть ли не единственный источник ложных срабатываний.

Во-вторых, Qihoo-360 — это мутный китайский **антивирус, про который никто не слышал**. Его результаты увидят только параноики, регулярно качающие кряки, поэтому привыкшие ориентироваться на VirusTotal (ну и китайцы).

В-третьих, у нормальных антивирусов есть возможность **сообщить о ложных срабатываниях**. Отправляете им свой файл, через какое-то время с какой-то вероятностью выходит обновление, в котором ваш файл больше не обнаруживается.

Учтите, что при изменении любого байта в вашем файле антивирус может снова начать срабатывать. Никаких гарантий. Просто "эвристики" действительно настолько бесполезны.

Comment: Ну по поводу "про который никто не слышал" - я бы так не сказал. По статистике, он 3-й по популярности в России, после антивируса касперского и avast. А вот способ распространения, насколько знаю, у него действительно "муторный" - автоматически устанавливается с различными програми(если не снять галочку), с "комплектом от Mail.Ru" , "Амиго" и прочей ересью..

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Репутация у этого антивируса подмоченная не только из-за способа распространения, но и из-за читерства для получения рейтинга.

Answer (score 0):

"Вирус" пропал на сканере Security 360, после того, как в окне настроек проекта во вкладке publish, я вернул все настройки к тем которые были по умолчанию.
(код самой програмы не менял)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]