# Как реализовать несертифицированный установщик, чтобы антивирусы не определяли его как вредоносное ПО?

Tags: c#, .net, семантика, антивирус

Написала установщик на C# .NET. Как он устанавливает игру:

- определяет системную директорию и создаёт в ней папку;
- развёртывает в эту папку файлы с архива, который получает по HTTP;
- создаёт ярлык на рабочем столе;
- регистрирует приложение в ОС (создаёт записи в реестре), указывая при этом путь к деинсталятору.

При скане на virustotal изначально было 2 детекта. Сегодня немного переделала (сделала запрос прав администратора в деинсталяторе), провела новый скан и в итоге уже 6 детектов (https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/2154645be54b586c5febb1f58fb6665b892bd5d35f9d48969d58e2b290db5703/detection). Что сделать, чтобы антивирусы не определяли мой установщик как зловред?

Comment: зачем создавать папку в системной директории?

Comment: @Grundy хороший вопрос. Решила сделать как делают все и не подумала, что моё ПО несертифицированное. Сейчас переделаю и напишу какой результат.

Comment: Все не засовывают в системные директории свои файлы. Для этого есть AppData например или что то в этом роде.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ заменила системную директорию на AppData - количество детектов так же и осталось равным 7-и.

Comment: @J.Huxley Мне кажется тут смело можно закрывать как дубликат на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537030/220553) вопрос. Более толкового по этому поводу вряд ли что можно сказать. В наше время большинство антивирусов являются сами "вирусами". Самый лучший "антивирус" - это голова на плечах с возможностью анализировать то, что мы закачиваем на свой компьютер. Я допустим уже как лет 7 не ставил чего либо из антивирусов и не поверите, не одного вируса! С точки зрения разработчика - тут ваша репутация превыше всего, она должна быть чистая, тогда к вам будет больше доверия пользователей.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если вы под виндой, то у вас антивирус встроенный, но вцелом согласен

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен, да. Но не поверите и он выключен =)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не считаю вопрос дубликатом из-за того, что здесь я описала функционал моего приложения. Пользователи могут написать мне что с этого функционала может являться подозрительным паттерном и как лучше это переделать (пример с заменой системной директории на AppData).

Comment: @J.Huxley Как я вам уже и написал, для пользователей важна ваша репутация. Если у вас будет все грамотно оформлено, будет например портфолио или ресурс который долго существует на рынке, ну или проект OpenSource - они поймут, что это ложное срабатывание и добавят в исключение/кинут репорт в тп. антивируса и та разберется, вирус это или нет. Ну а так вы нечего толком сделать то и не можете. Любое вмешательство в ресурсы системы может расцениваться антивирусом вредом (примерно об это написано в том ответе, из за этого считаю дублем). Не нравится срабатывание - пишите в тп. антивируса.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ портфолио ещё как такового нет. Так же и с временем существования на рынке. Только начинаю. Делать проект Open Source не вижу смысла, ведь зачем тогда столько времени разрабатывала игру? Вижу только один выход: написать в тп антивируса. Спасибо за совет.